# Package other than calibre for converting an RSS feed's entries to an ebook

Tags: software-recommendation, calibre, epub

Is there a package in the repositories (other than Calibre) that could be used to take an RSS feed and convert the entries into an ebook for reading?

Calibre seems a bit too bulky to use to simply grab a single feed and spit out the entries as perhaps an epub.

Calibre has a [manual section](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/news.html) for grabbing RSS feeds but I am not too keen on fiddling with Python.

Comment: Are you and Jorge open to having a python script do it? I might hack something together if you will.

Comment: Please don't cross post: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/551

Comment: is it acceptable for you to use non repository software?if so i know one,probably.

Comment: @Seth Similar questions, very different focus points.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat  I don't see the "very different" content.  What's added or subtracted in this question versus that?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract xml to text with just bash and wget.

e.g;

```
# Setup
URI=http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/index_rss.xml
LINES=20 #max number of lines
EXEC="wget -q -O temp.temp"
clear

# Start
$EXEC $URI
cat temp.temp | grep title |\

# use sed loop to delete all LFs bar last line
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' |\

#replace all titles and descriptions with LFs
sed -e 's/<title>/\n\n/g' |\
sed -e 's/<description>/\n/g' |\

# uncook
sed -e 's/&lt;/</g' |\
sed -e 's/&gt;/>/g' |\
sed -e 's/nbsp;/ /g' |\
sed -e 's/&amp;/+/g' |\

#delete URLs
sed -e 's/http.[^<]*//g' |\

#replace other angled brackets with space
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>/ /g' |\

head -n $(($LINES + 2)) |\
tail -n $(($LINES))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not software but I have used http://newstoebook.com/ and was impressed with how well it worked.